# Documentation on virtual folders

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, explorer

I am looking for documentation for the Windows API on how to make virtual folders. I am going to make sort of my own file system and would like to have an icon under "Computer" for that file system. I have seen other programs which has this type of solution like programs which allows me to explore a Linux file system under in the Explorer program. Much like the same solution I am going to make. I am yet to find any documentation on how to do this, or am I searching for the wrong stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a Shell Namespace Extension. An entry Point for documentation is [Creating Shell Data Source Objects and Extending the Shell Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521656).

An example of a almost complete Project can be found on codeplex: [An almost complete Namespace Extension Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7973/An-almost-complete-Namespace-Extension-Sample)
Also in the [Windows SDK 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), there is an example of using the Shell ExtensionNamespace (can be found in the folder "Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\winui\shell\shellextensibility\explorerdataprovider"). In this Folder you will also find a document which describes the programming model (Using the System Folder View.doc).

If you really want to create a "real" file System Driver, you might want to look at this SO article:
[Creating a File System "Driver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423718/creating-a-file-system-driver) which mainly referes to the [Ext2 file system driver project](http://www.fs-driver.org/).