# Smartcard Usb Drive Letter

Tags: c#, windows, filesystems, smartcard

I am able to enumerate all plugged smartcard devices on any machine. I can accomplish this by using P/Invoke (winscard.dll).

What I'm trying to do now is to create a virtual (usb) drive letter which represents my smartcard reader. I have no idea if this is possible.

Refence link for connected smartcard:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardestablishcontext

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use commonly used tags, Mr. bit, or your questions may not get noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a file system plugin for Windows, look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668940/add-or-extend-file-system-support-under-windows).

Not that you would achieve much, because smart card files typically have two byte file ID's instead of names. Futhermore, almost all files don't have files that Windows would recognize. There is no real way of listing directories other than ISO 7816-15, and you might not want to go *that* way. Finally, the most important stuff like PIN's and keys cannot be accessed if they are files.

So though it is an interesting idea, I'm not sure it would accomplish much, and it would be a heap of work.